# Girl who can see the future meets boy who can see the future, relationship problems ensue

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story online about 5 years or so ago (plus or minus a few) on a site that publishes lots of SF stories. It involved two people who could both see the future, one a girl (who is the protagonist) and one a boy.

If I remember correctly, the story starts out with the two of them on their first date. I think they're arguing about whether it was a good idea (and whether that mattered) and how their relationship will go. Their abilities work differently somehow -- I can't remember the details but I think the boy's was more specific -- and the difference turns out to be important later.

As the story develops, there is an important plot point involving a bicycle accident -- I think he damages her bike or vice versa? They do have a relationship and end up breaking up (in the manner according to her prediction, I think), which is also important. The girl has a roommate with whom the protagonist is always talking over the relationship.

There's a significant twist in the story:

> If I understood it correctly, it turns out that his ability is
>  straightforward precognition while her ability is more about being
>  able to surf through alternate worldlines to one where her prediction
>  is true, even if that requires a different past. From the narration,
>  it's not clear that she even realizes this is what she's doing. The
>  detail of the bike accident (which characters other than her describe
>  differently at different parts of the story) clues the reader that
>  this is what's going on.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? I think I read it around the time that Catherynne Valente's *The Girl Who Navigated Fairyland in a Ship of Her Own Making* was first being published in installments online, and may have even been in the same online magazine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like ["Six Months, Three Days"](http://www.tor.com/2011/06/08/six-months-three-days/) by Charlie Jane Anders.

The opening line is:

> The man who can see the future has a date with the woman who can see many possible futures.

Comment: Yes, that's it! The one site I didn't spend hours combing through -- I was certain it was an online magazine like Clarkesworld or Lightspeed. Thank you!

Comment: Lol that sounds like a nightmare, she would "know she's always right" and meanwhile that makes it happen...